# I have a response that has the same beginning but always some random number at the end, i want to compare using a wildcard, how can I do it?

Tags: c#, response, wildcard, string-comparison

This is my code:

```
if (resp == "AxlRose")
{
    Report.Success("User found");
}
else
{
    Report.Failure("User not found"); 
}
```

The response usually looks like this:
"AxlRose13123213" where the number always changes and is random, how can I include a wildcard in my request?

Comment: you'd use the [String.StartsWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-6.0) method instead of the equality operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore any trailing characters, you could use the `StartsWith` method of the String object:

```
if (resp.StartsWith("AxlRose"))
{
    Report.Success("User found");
}
else
{
    Report.Failure("User not found");
}
```

Note that I won't look at how correct this is in terms of proper user authentication (not), just addressing the question strictly technically.

Comment: Thanks! this looks good however I get this message: The name 'StartsWith' is bound to a method and cannot be used like a property

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake the response is within a json and need to extract it, continue learning...